# C - Switch Context and Store Old in Queue

Tags: c, multithreading, ucontext

I'm trying to implement a thread switcher in c using the `ucontext.h` library.

I am doing this using a queue system where the next thread to run is at the front of the queue. When a thread pauses; I pop the node at the top of the queue, switch the running context with the one stored in that node, and push the node back onto the queue. This looks something like this:

I have a test case where I place two threads in the queue. Each thread prints its ID before pausing. I expect the two to alternate. Instead the firs thread runs to completion and the second does not run. I've narrowed this problem down to the way I swap the threads:

QManager.c

```
void pause () {
    struct ThreadNode* t= QManagerPop(Q);
    swapcontext(t->context, t->context);
    QManagerPush(t);
}
```

Seemingly; this does not switch the running context with the one stored in `t->context'.

I am looking for a way to do this; place the current context in a variable `t->context' while at the same time resuming the context that was stored in that variable.

I tried the following based on some information I found online

QManager.c

```
void switch (ucontext_t* c) {
    volatile int isSwap = 0;
    int isGet = getcontext(c);
    if (!isSwap && isGet ==0) {
        isSwap = 1;
        setcontext(c);
    }
}

void pause () {
    struct ThreadNode* t= QManagerPop(Q);
    switch(t->context);
    QManagerPush(t);
}
```

This produces the same behaviour (with an additional segfault at the end).

Is there some way to do what I am looking to do? Maybe something with a temp variable? How would I deal with this variable when the context switches?

Comment: You accidentally passed the same pointer for both of `swapcontext`'s parameters.

Comment: This wasn't accidental. I want to load the context in t->context and save the previous context in t->context. It doesn't work but I don't know the correct approach.

Comment: Yes it is wrong. It's the reason my code does not work. I simply don't know the correct approach to doing what I want. I asked this question in the hopes of finding out and put my incorrect code in the question so that people can see what exactly I did that did not work.

Comment: It also  seems you expect `swapcontext` to return immediately so you can call `QManagerPush(t)` before anything else happens. But `swapcontext` will only return if you switch back to the context you switched away from, which you didn't save anywhere.

Comment: Re "*This wasn't accidental.*", Well, the parameters are `restrict`, and passing the same pointer twice violates that. /// Re "*I don't know the correct approach*", Well, you need more than one `ucontext_t`, for starters.

Comment: Re -  swapcontext returning immediately. Yes I realize now that is another problem with my code. However I still don't understand what exactly I have to do to load the context found in the queue head while pushing the old context onto the queue (in a way that will make run well after it is loaded again). How would this look like? What do I need to do?

Comment: You can't push your old context onto the queue after swapping. That "thread" is no longer executing! You need to pass a pointer to where it will be stored to `swapcontext`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use dynamic memory, but 1) you didn't allocate anything, 2) you'd have to push the allocated block unto the queue *before* calling `swapcontext` (which is fine), and 3) you'd need to deallocate the block you popped from the queue.

Comment: The names `QManagerPop` and `QManagerPush`  make no sense by the way. The `Q` suggests you have a queue, but push and pop are stack operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The two arguments to `swapcontext` context can't be the same pointer since the parameters are `restrict`.
- You can't push your old context onto the queue after swapping. That "thread" is no longer executing! It needs to be done before the swap.

---

Instead of allocating and deallocating all those threads, you could work with thread ids, which is to say indexes into an array of structures that contains the context and other data to a thread.

Then, switching context context becomes

```c
void switch_to_thread( ThreadId new_thread_id ) {
   ThreadId old_thread_id = current_thread_id;
   current_thread_id = new_thread_id;
   swapcontext(
      &( threads[ old_thread_id ].context ),
      &( threads[ new_thread_id ].context )
   );
}
```

and `pause` becomes

```c
void yield( void ) {
   QManagerEnqueue( q, current_thread_id );
   ThreadId new_thread_id = QManagerDequeue( q );
   switch_to_thread( new_thread_id );
}
```

---

Actually, if all the threads are in an array, then we don't need queue. We just need to find the next thread in the array.

```c
ThreadId get_next_thread( void ) {
   ThreadId thread_id = current_thread_id;
   while ( 1 ) {
      thread_id = ( thread_id + 1 ) % MAX_THREADS;

      int state = threads[ thread_id ].state;
      if ( state == STATE_CREATED || state == STATE_RUNNING )
         return thread_id;
   }
}

void yield( void ) {
   switch_to_thread( get_next_thread() );
}
```

This code comes from [this earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77299394/589924), where you can see these functions used.

---

Note these fixes:

- `void f()` doesn't mean the function takes no argument.

Note these renames:

- `Q` ⇒ `q`.
  It's not a module name or constant.
- `QManagerPush` ⇒ `QManagerEnqueue` and
  `QManagerPop` ⇒ `QManagerDequeue`.
  Push and pop are stack operations, not queue operations.
- `pause` ⇒ `yield`.
  `yield` or `cede` are more appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

Welp I solved my problem. Thank you to @ikegami for pointing out that i cant call swapcontext with the same arguments nor expect the function to push after swapping. my code now looks like

```
void pause () {
    struct ThreadNode* t= QManagerPop(Q);
    struct ThreadNode* s= malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadNode));
    s -> context = malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t));
    QManagerPush(s);
    swapcontext(QManagerTail(Q)->context, t->context);
}
```

Comment: You never free `t` and `t->context`.